# Sort criterion for 2 lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists:

```
a = [2,3,1,4]
b=[two, three, one, four]
```

I need to sort the first list in ascending order, but I need the second list ( made up of strings) to follow the same sorting.
That is, I expect to get the following result:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [one, two, three, four]
```

does anyone have a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`aa, bb = zip(*sorted(zip(a, b)))`

BTW, you will need to quote the items in the second list, unless those are variable references.

The inner zip puts the two lists together into one tuple:

`[(2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (1, 'one'), (4, 'four')]`

The sorted does the sort. Tuples sort by their first key:

`[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]`

The outer zip & * operator usage is an "unzip a list" pythonic trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It worked fine when I put together a list of integers and a list of strings, but when I did the same with a list of integers and another list of arrays I got this: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: aa, bb = zip(*sorted(zip(a, b), key=lambda x: x[0]))

Answer (score 1):

Use: `sorted(zip(a,b))`

We are basically zipping the two lists together. They need to have same length.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two lists into a list of two-element tuples and sort it:

```
mylist = [
    (2, "two"),
    (3, "three"),
    (1, "one"),
    (4, "four")
]
mylist.sort()
```

It will be sorted in order of the first element.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It worked fine when I put together a list of integers and a list of strings, but when I did the same with a list of integers and another list of arrays I got this: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"